# Sort array having numbers in "A/B" format?

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, sorting

I got an array like :`arr = ["1/8", "2/8", "1/17", "4/17", "3/5", "1/2"]`
Now I need to get a sorted array like

```
[
"1/17",
"4/17",
"1/8",
"2/8",
"3/5",
"1/2"
]
```

So anyone has any good suggestions? Thanks in advance!

PS: this is just an example, maybe the datas are others , but all in A/B format.

Comment: you want the solution in js or java?

Comment: You have to tell us, how you sort it. By the number after the slash?

Comment: @AniruddhAgarwal any is ok. Better js ;)

Comment: I assume you want to sort by values, so you can use ScriptEngineManager to evaluate along with basic Comparator.

Comment: What is the logic of sorting?

Comment: @ThomasBöhm for A/B, I wanna bigger B first and then A in asc order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In js, you can use `sort`

```js
var arr = ["1/8", "2/8", "1/17", "4/17", "3/5", "1/2"];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
  let aParts = a.split("/");
  let bParts = b.split("/");

  //Given value A/B

  if (aParts[1] === bParts[1]) return aParts[0] - bParts[0]; //Check if B is the same, if it is use A to sort
  return bParts[1] - aParts[1];                              //B is not the same, so sort using b
});

console.log(arr);
```

---

Shorter version:

```js
var arr = ["1/8", "2/8", "1/17", "4/17", "3/5", "1/2"];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
  let x = a.split("/"),y = b.split("/");
  return x[1] === y[1] ? x[0] - y[0] : y[1] - x[1];
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method for sorting and [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) for sorting apply on second element after `/`.

> In ES5

```js
var result = ["1/8", "2/8", "1/17", "4/17", "3/5", "1/2", '1/2'].sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a == b) {
    console.log('value same', a, b);
    return 0
  }
  a = parseInt(a.split('/')[1]);
  b = parseInt(b.split('/')[1]);
  return a > b ? -1 : (a < b ? 1 : 0);
});

console.log(result)
```

> In ES6

```js
let result= ["1/8", "2/8", "1/17", "4/17", "3/5", "1/2",'2/8'].sort((a, b) => {
 if (a == b) {
    console.log('value same',a,b);
    return 0
  }
  a = +a.split('/')[1];
  b = +b.split('/')[1];
  return a > b ? -1 : (a < b ? 1 : 0);
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: No, this is not ok because is not a guarantee to sort using the last part.

Answer (score 0):

arr = ["1/8", "2/8", "1/17", "4/17", "3/5", "1/2"]

Create a hashMap or any data Structure which can hold key value pair (let’s assume name is arrMap)

Create an array which can hold float values (let’s assume name is tempArray)

```
loop: arr elements

1st element is 1/8

    Use substring method to get before slash and after slash values
    Hence u will get
      Var beforeSlash = 1 // in string format

      Var afterSlash = 8     // in string format

      These are in string hence Do parseInt     

         Var beforeSlash = 1 // in int format

         Var afterSlash = 8  // in int format

         Var division =  beforeSlash / afterSlash; // division is in float

         Put in arrMap the value division with key “ beforeSlash / afterSlash” 
         [here it will be  key: value is “1/8” : 0.125]
         Put division in tempArray. // tempArray [0.125] 
end loop
```

After the execusion the tempArray will be [0.125, 0.25, 0.0588, 0.235, 0.6, 0.5]

Apply any default sort method

eg. tempArray.sort()

The final tempArray will become [0.0588, 0.125, 0.235, 0.25, 0.5, 0.6 ]

After the execusion the arrMap will be

[

"1/8"   :0.125,

"2/8"   :0.25,

"1/17"  :0.0588,

"4/17" :0.235,

"3/5"   :0.6,

"1/2"   : 0.5

]

Replace tempArray values with there keys from hashMap

Hence finalArry becomes
[   "1/17", "1/8", "4/17", "2/8", "1/2", "3/5"]